# OnClickListeners: Preventing memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, onclicklistener

Tapping the button multiple times opens many new screens(Activities). To prevent this I attached a flag to prevent this. But it may cause memory leaks. After searching a lot I found one solution. It is to attach the OnClick listeners onResume and set them null on onDetach and when the button is clicked. But I am finding it difficult to implement this.

My Code :-

```
 private static int flag = 0;
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   binding.createEventFab.setOnClickListener(view ->{
       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateEventActivity.class);
        if(flag == 0){
            startActivity(intent);
            flag++;
       }
    });
}
@Override
 public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        flag = 0;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats Causing the leak ? I don't think there should be any leak for an anonymous object .. Are you using any leak detection library like Leak-canary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so there is a leak here, but the real problem is that you are allowing user to press button multiple times, so you need debouncing listener.

The best what you can do is use [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding), since you can easy use it in another classes.

Here is sample code below:

```
RxView.clicks(/* Your view */)
        .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe(s -> { /* Your code */  });
```

or in Kotlin, with nice extension

```
fun View.actionOnClick(function: () -> Unit): Disposable {
    return clicks()
        .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe { function() }
}
```

Don't forget to add these to `CompositeDisposable` and `clear()` them in `onDestroy()` (for `Activity`) or `onDestroyView()` (for `Fragment`) method.

---

Another option is use [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) with `@OnClick(/* viewId */)`, but RxBinding is preferred if you would like to easy switch to Kotlin in future (and for Kotlin, another possibility is use coroutines, but deboucers using coroutines can be hard to implement for some cases, like watcher for `EditText`).

Answer (score -1):

You can set your click listeners in a normal way. And you can set the `launchMode` of the activity to `singleTop` in your `Manifest.xml` file. Your activities shouldn't leak. For further reading you can take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) about the `launchMode`